# get the default value of select one menu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two classes where the mapping is:

> User   *--------------------1    Sexe

I have the list of users on **list-users.component.html**. After selecting one user for modification, I'll be redirected to **modify-user.component.html**

Bellow are the required files:
* the **list-users.component.html** is:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sexe</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="!loader">
        <tr *ngFor="let user of userbs | async" style="width: 1500px;">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.sexe.libelle}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where `userbs` is obtained by using the service `userService.getUsersList()` with the type `Observable<User[]>`.

the **modify-user.component.html** is:

```html
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Sexe</label>

        <select (change)="onChangeSexeName($event)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
            <option *ngFor="let sexe of sexes" [ngValue]="sexe" [selected]="selected">{{sexe.name}}</option>
        </select>
        ==> Original Sexe: {{selectedSexeUserCompare.name}}
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
```

and **modify-user.component.ts** is:

```js
export class ModifyUserComponent implements OnInit {
    editForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;
    private selectedSexe;
    users: Observable<User[]>;
    libelleSexe: string;
    usrId: String;
    selectedSexeUserCompare = { num: localStorage.getItem("selectedSexeId"), name: localStorage.getItem("selectedSexeName") }
    sexeName: String;

    sexes: Array<Object> = [
        { num: 1, name: "Female" },
        { num: 2, name: "Male" }
    ];

    compareFn(a, b) {
        console.log(a, b, a && b && a.num == b.num);
        return a && b && a.num == b.num;
    }

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sexeName = localStorage.getItem("sexeLibelle");

        let userId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
        this.usrId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
        if (!userId) {
            alert("Invalid action.")
            this.router.navigate(['users-list']);
            return;
        }

        this.userService.getUserEntityId(+userId).map(se => se.sexe.libelle).subscribe((response) => {
            this.libelleSexe = response;
            localStorage.setItem("sexeLibelle", this.libelleSexe);
        });

        this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [],
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
            age: ['', Validators.required],
            active: ['false']
        });

        this.userService.getUserId(+userId).subscribe(data => {
            this.userService.getUserEntityId(+userId).map(se => se.sexe.libelle).subscribe((response) => {
                this.libelleSexe = response;
                let sexe = this.userService.getSexeByLibelle(this.libelleSexe);
                localStorage.setItem("sexeLibelle", this.libelleSexe);
                this.editForm.patchValue(data);
            });
        });
    }

    onChangeSexeName($event) {
        this.selectedSexe = $event.target.options[$event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.userService.updateUsera(this.editForm.value, this.selectedSexe).subscribe(data => {
            this.router.navigate(['users-list']);
        },
            error => {
                alert(error);
            });
    }
}
```

On **modify-user** page, I get usually **the first sexe libelle of the list of sexes** (Female, Male) and **NOT the correct sexe libelle**, exactly like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AQCX.png) displayed.

Could you please help me solving that issue ?.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why you are not adding `sex` to your `editForm`. Add `sex` to your `editForm` and initialize it with the value stored in your `localStorage`.

```js
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    sex: [selectedSexeUserCompare.num, Validators.required]
    // Add form controls here
});
```

Another issue I noticed in your HTML is that you are setting the `ngValue` in your `options` to the entire `sexe` object. You should rather set it to a unique value such as the `num` property in your `sexe` object.

**modify-user.component.html**

```html
<select formControlName="sex" (change)="onChangeSexeName($event)" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option *ngFor="let sexe of sexes" [ngValue]="sexe.num">
        {{sexe.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Edit**: Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-initialization)

Comment: Hello Sir @Nash11, thanks a lot for your help. But still got the first sexeLibelle (Female) which is wrong.

Comment: Check out the working example I have added on StackBlitz. I would also suggest you use better variable naming conventions so as to improve readability and avoid simple mistakes.

Comment: Hello Sir @Nash11, yes it works as well, but I have to keep the function `onChangeSexeName($event)` as I described. Thanks again